# What's a best practice for storing statistical data for analytics?

Tags: mongodb, redis, analytics, metrics

I want to store data for pages visited to my site by users. If each page has a `page_id`, and each user has both a `session_id` and `user_id`, would using something like Redis be overkill, or should i just go with a basic text log file?

The reason I am thinking about a session_id is to ignore visits to the same page from the same session_id. I want to track the user_id so I'll be able to build  a graph of users to viewed pages.

The app uses MySQL, and I can certainly use that, I'm only considering Redis because of its fast write speed. I can also use MongoDB, but if these are unnecessary approaches then I don't have to. Theoretically, the size of these metrics could grow quite large--at that point, is Redis a viable option? Just trying to figure out what you have had success with.

Comment: Read some the the relatedreal-world use-case on MongoDB site here. http://www.10gen.com/use-case/high-volume-data-feeds That can give you some insight

Comment: Thank you for the link. I found a timely video on there that is very similar to what I want to accomplish. I'll be using MongoDB. [MongoDB For Analytics](http://www.10gen.com/presentations/mongo-chicago-2011/mongodb-for-analytics). (Happy to accept your answer if you'll make this an answer rather than a comment)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read some the the relatedreal-world use-case on MongoDB site here. 10gen.com/use-case/high-volume-data-feeds That can give you some insight

Comment: Thank you--went with MongoDB, specifically: http://www.10gen.com/presentations/mongo-chicago-2011/mongodb-for-analytics